Power Automate - Web Scraping only articles published on a specified date?
I am learning how to use Power Automate to collect daily information (including headlines, news summaries, published date and links) from several websites, and then all collected data is stored in an excel file with predefined headers: title, summary, published date, link with each data on website for each excel sheet.
I want to create a Flow that will do the following steps:
Step 1:
Open the excel file named "Website" and click on the link in sheet named "Website" to open it on Microsoft Edge  
Click here to see the image
 
Step 2: Check all the articles on that website (for this example: The Poultry Site | Home) that were published on the specified date, e.g., 29th April 2024 and copy all relevant information of those articles (title, summary, article link, published date).
Note here: I want to make the flow dynamic which means whenever I give a specific date in the flow, the tool only collects articles published on that date and ignores the ones published on other dates. 
Click here to see the image
 
Step 3: After collecting all required information, I want to save the data in a sheet that is created to only store data (selected information of required articles) of that website. In this example, the sheet named "ThePoultrySite" only contains data published on Website:  The Poultry Site | Home.
Click here to see the image
 
Step 4: The flow starts with other websites listed on the sheet named "Website" and flow repeats the steps from 1 to 3 on each other websites.
Click here to see the image
 
Comment:
I have struggled with this task for several weeks and found no solution available on the internet, including this forum. 
Any help, ideas, tips from the experts is much appreciated and gratefully noted.
Thank you for your help.
I want to use Power Automate to collect information (including headlines, news summaries, published date and links) from several websites at a specified date. Once finished, all collected data is stored in an excel file with predefined headers: title, summary, published date, link with each data on website for each excel sheet.
